# Display <img> on <div> hover

Tags: jquery, css, image, html, hover

I have this code:

```
<div class="bigroundlink" >
    <img class="cross" src="img.png" style="position:absolute; display:none;" />
</div>
```

And would like to display that image when the user hovers the div. How can i do it ? Feel free to use/add (if needed) id's to the elements, JQuery and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works very fine with jquery!

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bigroundlink").hover(function(){
        $(".bigroundlink .cross").show();
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks ! used this just added another param to the hover function to hide the img :) I'll edit the question with the sollution i used [btw You can accept an answer in 5 minutes, 5min :p]

Answer (score 5):

This? (pure css)

```
.bigroundlink img { visibility: hidden; }
.bigroundlink:hover img { visibility: visible; }
```

And remove the embedded styles ons your img tag

Comment: Edited, remove style attribute from your img tag. And prefer visibility to display, so the container keep the good dimensions

Comment: What you want is not very clear. Missing some context. Is there a reason for an absolute position? Is there a reason to show the image on hovering the div and not the image itself?

Comment: Why that? It depends context, but with display none, the div has no dimensions, and can't be hovered.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set a width and height to the DIV if the img will not be displayed. Then:

CSS:

```
.bigroundlink {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.bigroundlink').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.cross').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so, you need

```
$(function() {
$(".bigroundlink").hover(
});
```

and there impl [.fadeTo jquery  Effects](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)